Is the product of torus and sphere a cover of the symmetric square of torus?
Let $T$ denote the $2$-dimensional torus and $T^{(2)}$ denote its symmetric square (which is the orbit space of the canonical $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on the $4$-torus $T \times T$).
One can see $T^{(2)}$ as a non-trivial $S^2$ bundle over $T$, i.e. there is a fiber bundle $S^2\hookrightarrow T^{(2)}\xrightarrow{f} T$. I suspect that the product $S^2\times T^2$ is a (finite) cover of $T^{(2)}$, however I do not have a proof. I believe the structure group on such a bundle is the isometry group of $S^2$, and perhaps that can help us get a covering map $p:S^2 \times T\to T^{(2)}$? Can someone please help me decide if there is such a covering? Thanks!

Yes, $T \times S^2$ covers $T^{(2)}$.
We can endow $T$ with a group structure. With this structure, it is not hard to check that the quotient of $T$ by the inverse map is $S^2$.
So $T \times S^2$ is the quotient of $T^2$ by the involution fixing the first torus and acting as the inverse map on the second torus.
The map $(x,y) \to \{ x+y, x-y\}$ from $T^2$ to $T^{(2)}$ is fixed by this involution, and hence factors through the quotient $T \times S^2$, giving the desired covering.

I understand that the above map from $T^2$ to $T^{(2)}$ factors via $T\times S^2$ but can you please explain why the factor map $p:T\times S^2 \to T^{(2)}$ should be a covering?

@SRhonda maybe I don't know what you mean by covering.

@SRhonda This presents $T^{(2)}$ as the quotient of $T^2$ by the group generated by of the automorphisms where we add a $2$-torsion point to $x$ and $y$ and the automorphism where we negate $y$. On the other hand, $T \times S^2$ is the quotient of only the automorphism negating $y$. Since the automorphism negating $y$ is the only nontrivial one that has a fixed point, $T^{(2)}$ is the quotient of $T \times S^2$ by a fixed-point-free group action and hence $T \times S^2$ is a covering space of $T^{(2)}$.
